LSTM Machine learning input/output question
I need some help with the below criteria

Model input shape must be (BATCH_SIZE, N_PAST = 10, N_FEATURES = 1), since the testing infrastructure expects a window of past N_PAST = 10 observations of the 1 feature to predict the next N_FUTURE = 10 observations of the same feature.
Model output shape must be (BATCH_SIZE, N_FUTURE = 10, N_FEATURES = 1)
The last layer of your model must be a Dense layer with 1 neuron since the model is expected to predict observations of 1 feature.

Below is my code:
# Code to define your model.
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([

   
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation='tanh', input_shape=(N_PAST, N_FEATURES), return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_FEATURES)
])


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-5, momentum=0.9) # YOUR CODE HERE
model.compile(

    loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(),
    optimizer=optimizer,
    metrics=["mae"]
)
model.fit(
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    train_set, validation_data=valid_set, epochs=200
)

return model

Can someone help to see where are the issues since it says my code can't meet the criteria.
Many thanks.
I expect my code to meet the criteria described in my question
